# How to create_or_update a unique and present validation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, update-attributes

Why I can't update attributes since I'm not updating a unique field?

urlmd5 and url both has uniqueness validation:

```
validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates :urlmd5, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

This Works:

```
    ParserUrl.where(urlmd5: p[:urlmd5]).first_or_initialize.update_attributes!(
        user_id: item.user_id, parser_id: item.parser_id
    )
```

This doesn't works:

```
    ParserUrl.where(url: p[:url], urlmd5:p[:urlmd5]).first_or_initialize.update_attributes!(
        user_id: item.user_id, parser_id: item.parser_id
    )

I got error 'unable to update existing record'...
```

Is first_or_initialize.update_attributes! the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Can you give the full error, exactly as it appears? Also what exactly is `p` in this context?

Comment: I'd guess you have a record which has already got the p[:url] value in url OR the p[:urlmd5] value in urlmd5 but not both.  So first_or_initialize is not finding the combination of both, so is initializing a record with both but the uniqueness constraint still applies to one of the fields.

Comment: Could it be that you want uniqueness only on BOTH fields combined?  You'll need to change your validation.  `validates :urlmd5, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :url}` and the same for the inverse.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn See my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was I haven't passed unique values to first_or_initialize, so when new instance is created it failed due to a lack of uniqueness, presence or both.

You need to pass unique values to first_or_initialize:

```
ParserUrl.where(urlmd5: p[:urlmd5]).
    first_or_initialize(url: p[:url].to_s, urlmd5: p[:urlmd5]).
    update_attributes!(user_id: item.user_id, parser_id: item.parser_id)
```

Another way in Rails 4:

1) Only hit the DB one time:

```
ParserUrl.find_or_initialize_by(url: p[:url].to_s, urlmd5: p[:urlmd5]).
    update_attributes!(user_id: item.user_id, parser_id: item.parser_id)
```

2) This will hit the DB two times (not desirable):

```
ParserUrl.find_or_create_by!(url: p[:url].to_s, urlmd5: p[:urlmd5]).
    update_attributes!(user_id: item.user_id, parser_id: item.parser_id)
```